# Can Not Pin Auto Layout Right Anchor to UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I'm trying to add an overlay view on top of my table view. It should be displayed above the cells, and scroll along them.

This overlay view should have a fixed height and span the whole width of the table view, all laid out using autolayout constraints.

I am setting constraints on the following anchors:

```
let yPosition: CGFloat = 100.0
let fixedHeight: CGFloat = 10.0

subview.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: fixedHeight).isActive = true

subview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.topAnchor, constant: yPosition).isActive = true

subview.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.leftAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

subview.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.rightAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
```

However, at runtime (as revealed by the view hierarchy debugger) my subview has a width of zero. The debugger also reveals that the constraints are there, just as I set them.

If I replace the right anchor constraint with a width constraint (e.g.):

```
subview.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 100.0).isActive = true
```

...then it is displayed at the specified width (but I need it to span the whole width of the table view).

**What am I missing?**

Perhaps `UITableView`'s right anchor somehow is defined to coincide with the left anchor, and that causes my subview to have zero width?

---

If instead, I constrain against the right anchor of my view controller's main view (superview of the table view), I get the expected result.

Comment: try setting equalwidth anchor subView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(tableView.widthAnchor).active = true

Comment: Its working on my side! https://unsee.cc/naromugi/ copy & paste to browser

Comment: @karthikeyan Thank you; Constraining left anchor and equal widths works.

Comment: @Mr.Bista I'm creating the subview programmatically as well as all the constraints. And yes, all the views involved have `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set to `false`.

Comment: I also did the same, did you check my code in above image, its similar i think.

Comment: @NicolasMiari shall i add it as answer, it may helpful to others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting **equalWidth** constraint

```
equalwidth anchor subView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(tableView.widthA‌​nchor).active = true
```

Comment: Thank you; your solution works. But I still don't understand why setting left and right anchors isn't enough (or what else is wrong with my setup that I missed...).

Comment: what are constraints to your tableview?

Comment: The table view is constrained left, right to superview margins (`UIViewController.view`), bottom to bottom layout guide, top to sibling view (which is in turn constrained to top layout guide - a custom header).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but did you happen to look at translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints ? This screwed up my anchor-based autolayout.